# Is there an idea to jump Sunday date (the iteration number 7) in this code and show all dates?

Tags: php, datetime, foreach

I want help to show dates without Sunday(date) and show the day of( 2019- 
    07-27).
    I want result like this : twice (Monday -> Saturday) between 2019-07-15 
    and 2019-07-27. this exemple is just for 2 iterations ($arrayOfMerchs) 
    but the number of day is 12(static) without Sunday.

```
Note : the date change every time. Exp :[2019-07-29 to 2019-08-10],[2019-08-12 to 2019-08-24] ...etc
```

If there is another way to get this code better I'm so thankful.

```
I want result like this:

2019-07-15 00:00:00 //Monday
2019-07-16 00:00:00
2019-07-17 00:00:00
2019-07-18 00:00:00
2019-07-19 00:00:00
2019-07-20 00:00:00 //Saturday
2019-07-22 00:00:00 //Monday
2019-07-23 00:00:00
2019-07-24 00:00:00
2019-07-25 00:00:00
2019-07-26 00:00:00
2019-07-27 00:00:00 // Saturday

2019-07-15 00:00:00  //Monday
2019-07-16 00:00:00
2019-07-17 00:00:00
2019-07-18 00:00:00
2019-07-19 00:00:00
2019-07-20 00:00:00 //Saturday
2019-07-22 00:00:00 //Monday
2019-07-23 00:00:00
2019-07-24 00:00:00
2019-07-25 00:00:00
2019-07-26 00:00:00
2019-07-27 00:00:00 //Saturday


This is my script :   
<?php
   $begin = new DateTime('2019-07-15');
   $end = new DateTime('2019-07-27');

   $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
   $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
   $arrayOfMerchs = array(1,2);
   $arrayofPlannings = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

   $cpt = 0;
   foreach ($arrayOfMerchs as $merch) {
    foreach ($arrayofPlannings as $planning) {
        foreach ($period as $dt) {
            $cpt ++;
            if($cpt == 7){continue;}
            echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>";
        }
        break;

    }
    echo " "."<br>";
   }

The result of this code like:

2019-07-15 00:00:00 
2019-07-16 00:00:00
2019-07-17 00:00:00
2019-07-18 00:00:00
2019-07-19 00:00:00
2019-07-20 00:00:00 // 
2019-07-22 00:00:00
2019-07-23 00:00:00
2019-07-24 00:00:00
2019-07-25 00:00:00
2019-07-26 00:00:00 
                // date of2019-07-27 00:00:00 not showing 

2019-07-15 00:00:00
2019-07-16 00:00:00
2019-07-17 00:00:00
2019-07-18 00:00:00
2019-07-19 00:00:00
2019-07-20 00:00:00
2019-07-21 00:00:00 // I dont want to show Sunday
2019-07-22 00:00:00
2019-07-23 00:00:00
2019-07-24 00:00:00
2019-07-25 00:00:00
2019-07-26 00:00:00
             // date of2019-07-27 00:00:00 not showing
```

Comment: If you don’t want to create any output for Sundays - then simply check what week day the current date corresponds to, _before_ you make the output …?

Comment: @ The date is generated automatically, so I dont know which date is Sunday. that's why I use the iterations and count until the 7.

Comment: _“so I dont know which date is Sunday”_ - easy to check, by formatting the date “as” the weekday or number of the day in the week …

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date()` and `strtotime()`

```
$date_to_test = "<calculated_date_time_here>";
if(date("w",strtotime($date_to_test)) == 0){
    // it's a sunday so skip to the next iteration of the loop
    continue;
}
```

You can use that when looping through the dates, you don't need H:i:s to calculate the day but it doesn't matter if it is included.

Comment: Thank you, but i want just jump this date to 2019-07-22.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You can just add this if statement in the loop and use it to test the dates you are looping through.

Comment: I've added some extra logic to suit your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$start = new DateTime('2019-06-01');
$end = new DateTime('2019-06-30');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$notSundayDates = [];
foreach ($period as $day) {
    //check if day of the week is sunday
    if ($day->format('w') !== "0") {
        $notSundayDates[] = $day;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. now, I can loop into the $notSundayDate array and get the result i want. But I ask why the date 2019-06-30 not showing.

Comment: That's because 2019-06-30 is Sunday :)